# Body Render Issue with NavigationStack in XCode 14 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

In the following code, background color of the `ContentView` doesn't change after two seconds.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bool: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(root: {
            Group(content: {
                if bool {
                    Color.red
                } else {
                    Color.blue
                }
            })
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                        print(">>>")
                        bool = true
                    })
                })
        })
    }
}
```

However, when replacing `NavigationStack(root: {` with `NavigationView(content: {`, the problem disappears.

Is anyone facing the same problem, or am I doing something wrong? I am using XCode `14.0` beta 2 (`14A5229c`), and running it on iOS `16.0` (`20A5303i`). Issue happens on both, simulator and physical device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who knows... may be it is intentional may be it is a bug, submit feedback to Apple.

Meanwhile here is a workaround, tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

```
    NavigationStack {
        if bool {
            Color.red
        } else {
            Color.blue
        }
    }
    .id(bool)             // << here !!
```

*BTW, `Group` is not needed anymore in such cases.

Comment: Will report it. Actually, I used `Group` just to apply same modifier to both views. Your `id` modifier definitely seems to work (both, when applied to `NavigationStack`, and to its content). Thanks.